# Cypress - Changing viewport with preset doesnt affect viewportHeight or Width

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, viewport, e2e-testing

I'm starting cypress today and I have this scenario with test displaying a simple element whether I'm on mobile, tablet, or desktop.

So I use this method to change viewport which seems to works but the config doesn't change.

```js
cy.log("viewport");
cy.log(""+Cypress.config().viewportWidth) // logs 1000
cy.viewport(preset)
cy.log(""+Cypress.config().viewportWidth) // still logs 1000
```

Am I to understand that config() is the default config and is not updated by method `viewport`

And if so, how can you get the current viewport?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), of working with multiple viewports and is tied to the [`isMobile`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/search?q=isMobile) utility function.

Comment: thx, it can work, but that doesnt tell me why i can't get the viewport just after setting it ..